# подскажите как сгенерировать уникальные ключи для localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

есть список товаров, при клике на кнопку я получаю инфу о товаре и кладу ее в  localstorage и  вывожу этот товар на другой странице, но при добавлении второго товара он перезатирает первый, потому что ключ у меня один, подскажите как правильно для каждого товара сделать уникальный ключ.

получаю ключи:

```
function new_page(el){
    var img = $(el).parent().parent().find(".img").find(".fancyboxGallery").find("img").attr("src");
    var name = $(el).parent().find(".name").html();
    var articul = $(el).parent().find(".props").eq(1).html();
    var price = $(el).parent().find(".props").eq(5).html();
    var ost = $(el).parent().find(".props").eq(6).html();
    var sum = $(el).parent().find(".props").eq(7).html();

    localStorage.setItem("flag",true);
    localStorage.setItem("startPoint",img);
    localStorage.setItem("finishPoint",name);
    localStorage.setItem("distance",articul);
    localStorage.setItem("cost",price);
    localStorage.setItem("ostatoc",ost);
    localStorage.setItem("summa",sum);
}
```

вывожу их на другой страницу

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("flag")){
        var parent = $(".myTable");
        $("<tr>" + "<td><img src='" + localStorage.getItem("fstartPoint") + "'>" + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("finishPoint") + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("distance") + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("cost") + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("ostatoc") + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("summa") + "</td>" + "</tr>").appendTo(parent);
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("page").item(0).innerHTML+="Ошибочка";
    }
}
```

карточка товара (ее разметка)

```
<div class="itemBlock">
    <div class="img" title="Гирлянда С днем рождения!  (европодвес.подвесные цифры от 4 до 6)">
        <a rel="group" class="fancyboxGallery" href="pub/preview/72/1474361697_72086611f34b5ac63b779ac3dfa1ee97.jpg"><img src="pub/preview/72/1474361697_72086611f34b5ac63b779ac3dfa1ee97.jpg" width="295" height="260" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"><div class="props name">Наименование: Гирлянда С днем рождения!  (европодвес.подвесные цифры от 4 до 6)</div>
        <div class="props">Артикул: 9-14-0005</div>
        <div class="props">Формат: 1м 92 см</div>
        <div class="props">Отделка: </div>
        <div class="props">Текст внутри: нет</div>
        <div class="props">Код цены: 9-14</div>
        <div class="props">Остаток:Много</div>
        <div class="props">500p</div>
        <button class="toFavorite" onclick="new_page(this)">Добавить в избранное</button><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Очистить" onclick="localStorage.clear();"/>
        Цена доступна после регистрации</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) и [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var products = { 'product-01': {}, 'product-02': {} };

// Сохраняем:
localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));

// Получаем:
var storedProducts = localStorage.getItem('products');
console.log('storedProducts: ', JSON.parse(storedProducts));
```

Такого варианта должно быть достаточно для хранения простых строковых значений.

Comment: у меня динамически меняющееся кол-во товаров и в localStorage данные буду класться по ключу products, при втором добавлении они просто перезатрут его

Comment: сейчас мой код просто перезаписывает уже положенное значение, а как сделать чтобы он добавлял новое?

Comment: Как в примере выше:
`x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))` - это будет объект с продуктами из хранилища.
Модифицируете его и снова записываете в хранилище.
`localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(x));`